# Bash Vi-mode: Move back to last slash

Tags: bash, vi

I'm using Bash in vi mode with `set -o vi`.

Often I re-run a command but need to change the name of a file in the same directory.

Example:

```
mv /tmp/myfileA.txt /home/daniel/myfileA.txt
```

Then, I decide to also move another file:

```
mv /tmp/w00t.txt /home/daniel/w00t.txt
```

Typically I press the up-arrow key to get the last command, and press `b` until I get to the last slash character, and then insert the new file name. Since I do this very often, I'm wondering if there is an easy way to get the cursor just right after or on the last slash character.

Please note the above is only an example; I know I could do something like `mv /tmp/{myfileA,w00t}.txt ...` but often I simply type faster than I think :-)

Answer (score 2):

`T/` puts the cursor after the last `/` character, so:

<kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> `w00t.txt` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

or, to replace the just first word in the file name:

<kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> `w00t` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

or, if there are multiple words before the extension and you want to keep the extension:

<kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> `w00t` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Alternatively, with history expansion:

```
!!:h/w00t.txt
```

Comment: `lC` is a nice touch.

Comment: @jasonwryan actually `T` would have been better.

Comment: Indeed: that will come in very handy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Escape</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>

<kbd>/</kbd>

- <kbd>Escape</kbd> puts you in edit mode
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> Searches backwards for the pattern:
- <kbd>/</kbd>

You can then execute a number of different options:

- <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>: deletes to the end of the line
- <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>: the same

<kbd>i</kbd> Puts you back in insert mode...